# How to change form error message text color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change "This line cannot be empty" text color. I tried these:

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}

input:required:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

````html
<input class="inputs" type="email" name='email' placeholder="E-mail" required="" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('This Line cannot be empty')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" /> ```
````

Comment: What does `setCustomValidity` do?

Comment: The string you want to make red is passed to the `setCustomValidity` function. So it isn't the input text. It's the result of the function which probably creates a `span` aside the input or something similar.